# ignoresSafeArea not covering bottom of View

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to create the background for a background view for a popup, however the view doesn't cover the bottom even after I use `.ignoreSafeArea()`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Overlay<Content: View>: View {

    @State var opacity: Double = 0
    var content: Content

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.black.opacity(opacity).ignoresSafeArea()
            content
        }
        .onAppear { self.opacity = 0.5 }
        .onDisappear { self.opacity = 0 }
    }
}

struct ForgotPasswordView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            Overlay(content: Text(""))
                .previewDevice("iPhone 12")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)` should work.

Comment: I think you want `ZStack` not `VStack`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VStack` arranges its children in a vertical line.

What You see in the bottom area is your content which you pass in the view creation (here its your TextView).

```
struct Overlay<Content: View>: View {

    @State var opacity: Double = 0
    var content: Content

    var body: some View {
        ZStack { //<- here
            Color.black.opacity(opacity).ignoresSafeArea()
            content
        }
        .onAppear { self.opacity = 0.5 }
        .onDisappear { self.opacity = 0 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution i was able to come up with:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Overlay<Content: View>: View {

    @State var opacity: Double = 1
    var content: Content

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.black
                .opacity(0)
            content
        }
        .background(Color.black.opacity(opacity))
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        .onAppear { self.opacity = 0.5 }
        .onDisappear { self.opacity = 0 }
    }
}

struct ForgotPasswordView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            Overlay(content: Text("hi"))
                .previewDevice("iPhone 12")
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is an image of it working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntdtn.png)
if you want the `content` to be overlayed on top of the view you can use a `ZStack` with the color in the back and the content in the front. this can be implemented by removeing the V in `VStack` and replacing it with a Z. [Beutiful image of it working!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hk6c.png)